# How to determine if HTML Control is being displayed in page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'd like to know how could I get only the displayed controls in the screen in the very moment.

For example:

> If I have a scrollbar which precludes the user from seeing everything
>   below the page, I'd like to make a selector which selects only what the user can see in his screen now. It would also be nice If I could select everything he does not see.

Is that possible? How?

Thanks

Comment: For a plugin based approach, I'd suggest: [Viewport Selectors for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the offsets (say, as the user scrolls) of what the user can see:

```
var top = $(window).scrollTop();
var bottom = top + $(window).height();
```

Then, you can see if an element is within this range.

```
$('*').each( function() {
  var el = $(this);
  var offsetTop = el.offset().top;
  var inView = offsetTop >= top && offsetTop <= bottom;
  el.addClass( inView ? 'in-view' : 'out-of-view' );
} );
```

Obviously there are some downsides performance wise to doing this. Depending what you want to do with this information you could select only `input`s or whatever which might help.

Comment: Exactly what I thought (+1). The wildcard selector scares me though!

Comment: You'd be surprised how fast the wildcard selector actually is on modern browsers, but yes, if you want to do something special only to `button`s or `a`s in the view, then you can obviously improve this :)

Comment: This was a good approach! I handled the scroll event of the document and made some specific processing with the elements as long as the rest of the page is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an easy or elegant solution to this. What you could do is calculate the [offset position](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) of all elements and the [scroll offset](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to find out which elements are visible or not. This could become expensive if you have a lot of elements to check, but could work quite nicely otherwise.